# Where do I get test-stylesheets to be able to use xsltproc?

Tags: unit-testing, xslt-1.0, test-reporting

I'm little lost here. I'm using googltest framework and just want to transform the xml report to an html. I found that `xsltproc` does the job:

```
xsltproc style.xsl report.xml -o report.hmtl
```

but first I need to get a stylesheet. Just a basic-generic stylesheet so the result can be visualized on a browser, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've tagged this XSLT 2.0, but xsltproc only supports XSLT 1.0.

Secondly, without knowing what flavour of XML is in report.xml, there isn't really very much one can do by way of a useful generic transformation to HTML. There are attempts like this one:

[Generic XSLT to tabluate XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605906/generic-xslt-to-tabluate-xml)

but whether it produces results that work for you depend entirely on your input and desired output, which you haven't told us anything about.

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#generating-an-xml-report It says "t is based on the junitreport Ant task and can be parsed by popular continuous build systems like Hudson." like being something "standard" on unit-testing. The difference here is that I'm not using a build-system to generate the report but want to do it manually. I mean, isn't that something common or I'm the only one who asks for this?

Comment: So is this any use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164914/converting-xml-junit-report-to-html

Comment: `xunit-viewer` seems to be what I want although it have troubles to parse googletest report. Thank you Sir